# Can any of Batman's gadgets knock enemies unconscious?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

While Batman is not actively engaged in combat with enemies (Predator mode, Stealth, etc.), do any of the gadgets alone or possibly a combination of gadgets allow Batman to knock an ememy unconcious? I'm assuming no from what I've tried, but just wanted to see if I was missing anything.

**Edit:** I guess I should state, besides using the disruptor along with a proximity mine laid by the enemy.

Comment: Are you asking in the context of when you're actively engaging in combat with enemies, or from a distance/when they're unaware like in invisible predator?

Comment: @Kotsu Good point, in the context of invisible like a predator. I'll edit to clarify.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Off the top of my head:

- **Batarang**: Stun, drop weapon
- **Batclaw**: Disarm, and as @BlackBat reminds us, yank an enemy off a ledge.
- **Cryptographic Sequencer**: No combat applications.
- **Disruptor**: Use on a mine to KO nearby enemies.
- **Explosive Gel**: Stun and knock down an enemy. KO will only occur if a wall (even a weak one) explodes next to, above or below the enemy. Enemies may also be KO'ed by a non-wall blast if it knocks them off a ledge.
- **Freeze Grenade/Freeze Cluster Grenade**: immobilize only
- **Grapnel**: Upgraded Grapnel Boost will KO an enemy.
- **Line Launcher**: Line launcher kick will KO any enemies in the path, so will dropping down from the line for a takedown.
- **Remote Batarang**: Knock down stun at high speed or lock on. Getting it electrically charged first may do a knock out (I think it did in *AA*, I haven't tried that in *AC*).
- **Remote Electrical Charge**: Momentarily disrupts enemy, knocks down armored enemies.
- **Smoke Bomb**: Obscures enemy sight. Can stun a tight group of enemies.
- **Sonic Batarang**: Electrical discharge upgrade will KO 1 enemy equipped with a heart monitor.

Comment: Nice list. Thanks. I always forget about the line launcher while in Predator mode.

Comment: @DoozerBlake If you have a group to fight, try to align the line launcher to zip through most of them. Especially useful for taking out armored enemies.

Answer (score 4):

The Batclaw can be used to pull enemies into walls. This can occasionally induce unconsciousness... Likewise, it can be used to pull someone off of a raised platform, causing them to fall and, depending on the height of the fall, lose consciousness. This is particularly useful when you are in cover and above someone who happens to be on a raised platform below you (like on a landing at the top of a flight of stairs).